# Rails Mysql Results - fetch_fields method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, key

So I'm trying to get the column names from the sql results using the method fetch_fields. But that returns it in this odd way:

```
 > for keys in e.fetch_fields.each do
 >     puts keys
 >  end
#<Mysql::Field:0x1c2a7bc>
#<Mysql::Field:0x1c2a780>
#<Mysql::Field:0x1c2a744>
 => [#<Mysql::Field:name>, #<Mysql::Field:address>, #<Mysql::Field:city>]
```

How do I get it to show as name, address, city?

Answer (score 1):

Found that this is the correct way to get the names of each field:

```
> for keys in e.fetch_fields.each do
>     puts keys.name
>  end
```